# Crossgrading Debian buster from i386 to amd64

Tags: debian, 64-bit, apt, dpkg, debian-buster

I followed the instructions from https://wiki.debian.org/CrossGrading but after crossgrading dpkg, tar, apt everything breaks completely. For example, `apt upgrade`:

```
# LANG=C apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 console-common : Depends: kbd but it is not installed
 debconf : PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3~) but it is not installed
           Recommends: apt-utils (>= 0.5.1) but it is not installed
 debconf-i18n : Depends: liblocale-gettext-perl but it is not installed
                Depends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not installed
                Depends: libtext-charwidth-perl but it is not installed
 default-mysql-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.3 but it is not installed
 default-mysql-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.3 but it is not installed
 dhcp3-client : Depends: isc-dhcp-client but it is not installed
 dhcp3-common : Depends: isc-dhcp-common but it is not installed
 diff : PreDepends: diffutils but it is not installed
 host : Depends: bind9-host but it is not installed
 init-system-helpers : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.20.1-3) but it is not installed
 krb5-config : Depends: bind9-host but it is not installed
 libalgorithm-c3-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libapache-session-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                          Recommends: libdbi-perl but it is not installed
 libapache2-mod-perl2:i386 : Depends: libdevel-symdump-perl:i386 but it is not installable
                             Recommends: libapache2-reload-perl:i386 but it is not installable
 libapache2-reload-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                          Depends: libapache2-mod-perl2 but it is not installed
 libapache2-svn : Depends: libapache2-mod-svn but it is not installed
 libappconfig-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libauthen-radius-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libauthen-sasl-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libb-hooks-endofscope-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                              Depends: libvariable-magic-perl but it is not installed
 libbind-confparser-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libbit-vector-perl:i386 : Depends: libcarp-clan-perl:i386 but it is not installable
 libcache-cache-perl : Depends: libipc-sharelite-perl but it is not installed
                       Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libcarp-assert-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libcarp-clan-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libcgi-fast-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                    Depends: libfcgi-perl but it is not installed
 libcgi-pm-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                  Depends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not installed
 libclass-accessor-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                          Depends: libsub-name-perl but it is not installed
 libclass-c3-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                    Recommends: libclass-c3-xs-perl but it is not installed
 libclass-container-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                           Depends: libparams-validate-perl but it is not installed
 libclass-data-inheritable-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libclass-dbi-abstractsearch-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libclass-dbi-perl : Depends: libclone-perl but it is not installed
                     Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libclass-inspector-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libclass-makemethods-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libclass-method-modifiers-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libclass-trigger-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libclone-choose-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                        Recommends: libclone-perl but it is not installed or
                                    libclone-pp-perl but it is not installed
 libconfig-inifiles-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.19.5) but it is not installed or
                                    libscalar-list-utils-perl (>= 1:1.33)
 libconvert-binhex-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libcpan-changes-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libcrypt-rc4-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libdata-dump-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libdata-optlist-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                        Depends: libparams-util-perl but it is not installed
 libdata-perl-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                     Depends: liblist-moreutils-perl but it is not installed
 libdate-calc-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                     Depends: libbit-vector-perl (>= 7.4) but it is not installed
                     Recommends: libdate-calc-xs-perl but it is not installed
 libdate-manip-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libdbix-contextualfetch-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                                Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not installed
 libdbix-datasource-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                           Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not installed
 libdevel-callchecker-perl:i386 : Depends: libdynaloader-functions-perl:i386 but it is not installable
 libdevel-globaldestruction-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.14.0) but it is not installed
 libdevel-stacktrace-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libdevel-symdump-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libdigest-bubblebabble-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libdigest-hmac-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libdigest-perl-md5-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libdynaloader-functions-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libencode-locale-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 liberror-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libexception-class-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libexporter-tiny-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libfile-listing-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libfile-sharedir-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libfile-slurp-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libgetopt-long-descriptive-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                                   Depends: libparams-validate-perl but it is not installed
 libgraph-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libgraphviz-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libhash-merge-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libhtml-mason-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                      Depends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not installed
                      Depends: libparams-validate-perl but it is not installed
                      Recommends: libapache2-mod-perl2 but it is not installed
 libhtml-parser-perl:i386 : Depends: libhtml-tagset-perl:i386 but it is not installable
                            Recommends: libhttp-message-perl:i386 but it is not installable
 libhtml-tagset-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libhtml-template-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libhtml-tree-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                     Depends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not installed
                     Recommends: libhtml-format-perl but it is not installed
 libhttp-cookies-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libhttp-date-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libhttp-message-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libhttp-negotiate-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libima-dbi-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                   Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not installed
 libimport-into-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libio-html-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libio-socket-inet6-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                           Depends: libsocket6-perl but it is not installed
 libio-socket-ssl-perl : Depends: libnet-ssleay-perl (>= 1.85-2~) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installed
                         Depends: perl but it is not installed
                         Recommends: perl (>= 5.15.6) but it is not installed or
                                     libsocket-perl or
                                     libsocket6-perl but it is not installed
 libio-string-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libio-stringy-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libipc-run-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                   Depends: libio-pty-perl but it is not installed
 liblingua-en-inflect-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 liblist-moreutils-perl:i386 : Depends: libexporter-tiny-perl:i386 but it is not installable
 liblog-any-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 liblua5.1-sec-dev : Depends: lua-sec but it is not installed
 liblua5.1-sec1 : Depends: lua-sec but it is not installed
 liblwp-mediatypes-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 liblwp-protocol-https-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libmailtools-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libmath-base-convert-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libmd5-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.8.0-10) but it is not installed
 libmime-base32-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libmime-tools-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libmodule-build-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                        Depends: perl (>= 5.19.5) but it is not installed or
                                 libtest-harness-perl (>= 3.29)
                        Depends: perl (>= 5.21.3) but it is not installed or
                                 libcpan-meta-perl (>= 2.142060)
                        Recommends: libmodule-signature-perl but it is not installed
                        Recommends: libsoftware-license-perl (>= 0.103009) but it is not installed
 libmodule-implementation-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libmodule-runtime-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                          Depends: libparams-classify-perl but it is not installed
 libmoo-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
               Recommends: libclass-xsaccessor-perl (>= 1.18) but it is not installed
               Recommends: libsub-name-perl (>= 0.08) but it is not installed
 libmoox-handlesvia-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libmro-compat-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                      Recommends: libclass-c3-xs-perl but it is not installed
 libnamespace-autoclean-perl : Depends: libsub-identify-perl but it is not installed
                               Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libnamespace-clean-perl : Depends: libsub-identify-perl but it is not installed
                           Depends: libsub-name-perl but it is not installed
                           Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libnet-daemon-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libnet-dns-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                   Recommends: libnet-dns-sec-perl but it is not installed
                   Recommends: libnet-libidn-perl but it is not installed
 libnet-dns-sec-perl:i386 : Depends: libnet-dns-perl:i386 (>= 1.08) but it is not installable
 libnet-http-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                    Depends: perl (>= 5.19.8) but it is not installed or
                             libio-socket-ip-perl (>= 0.26)
 libnet-ip-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libnet-smtp-ssl-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libole-storage-lite-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libpackage-stash-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                         Recommends: libpackage-stash-xs-perl but it is not installed
 libpackage-variant-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libpam-krb5:i386 : Depends: krb5-config:i386 but it is not installable
 libpam-runtime : Depends: libpam-modules (>= 1.0.1-6) but it is not installed
 libparallel-forkmanager-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libparams-validate-perl:i386 : Depends: libmodule-implementation-perl:i386 but it is not installable
 libparse-debianchangelog-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                                 Depends: liblocale-gettext-perl but it is not installed
 libparse-recdescent-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libpath-tiny-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                     Recommends: libunicode-utf8-perl but it is not installed
 libplrpc-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.6.0-16) but it is not installed
                 Depends: libstorable-perl or
                          perl-modules (>= 5.8.0-10)
 libpod-markdown-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                        Depends: perl (>= 5.18.0) but it is not installed or
                                 libpod-simple-perl (>= 3.27)
                        Recommends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not installed
 libpod-readme-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                      Depends: perl (>= 5.19.5) but it is not installed or
                               libscalar-list-utils-perl (>= 1:1.33)
                      Recommends: libtype-tiny-xs-perl but it is not installed
 libreadonly-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libref-util-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                    Recommends: libref-util-xs-perl but it is not installed
 librole-tiny-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libsnmp-info-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                     Depends: libnetaddr-ip-perl but it is not installed
                     Depends: libsnmp-perl but it is not installed
 libspreadsheet-parseexcel-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                                  Depends: libjcode-pm-perl but it is not installed
                                  Depends: libunicode-map-perl but it is not installed
 libspreadsheet-writeexcel-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libsql-abstract-limit-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                              Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not installed
 libsql-abstract-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libsql-statement-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                         Depends: libclone-perl but it is not installed
                         Depends: libparams-util-perl but it is not installed
                         Recommends: libdbi-perl but it is not installed
                         Recommends: libtext-soundex-perl but it is not installed or
                                     perl (< 5.17.9) but it is not installed
 libsql-translator-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                          Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not installed
                          Recommends: libgd-perl but it is not installed
                          Recommends: libjson-perl but it is not installed
                          Recommends: libtemplate-perl but it is not installed
                          Recommends: libxml-libxml-perl but it is not installed
                          Recommends: libyaml-perl but it is not installed
 libstrictures-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libsub-exporter-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libsub-exporter-progressive-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libsub-install-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libsub-quote-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libswitch-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libtemplate-perl:i386 : Depends: libappconfig-perl:i386 (>= 1.56) but it is not installable
 libtext-autoformat-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libtext-recordparser-perl : Depends: liblist-moreutils-perl but it is not installed
                             Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libtext-reform-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libtext-tabulardisplay-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libtext-wrapi18n-perl : Depends: libtext-charwidth-perl but it is not installed
 libtie-ixhash-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libtimedate-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libtry-tiny-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libtype-tiny-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                     Recommends: libscalar-list-utils-perl (>= 1:1.40)
                     Recommends: libtype-tiny-xs-perl but it is not installed
 libuniversal-moniker-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libwww-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
               Depends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not installed
               Recommends: libhtml-form-perl but it is not installed
               Recommends: libhtml-format-perl but it is not installed
               Recommends: libhttp-daemon-perl but it is not installed
 libwww-robotrules-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libxml-libxml-perl:i386 : Depends: libxml-namespacesupport-perl:i386 but it is not installable
                           Depends: libxml-sax-perl:i386 but it is not installable
 libxml-namespacesupport-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libxml-sax-base-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libxml-sax-expat-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                         Depends: libxml-parser-perl but it is not installed
 libxml-sax-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libxml-simple-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libxml-twig-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                    Depends: libxml-parser-perl but it is not installed
                    Recommends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not installed
                    Recommends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not installed
 libxml-writer-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 libxml-xpath-perl : Depends: perl but it is not installed
                     Depends: libxml-parser-perl but it is not installed
                     Depends: libscalar-list-utils-perl
 mailx : Depends: bsd-mailx but it is not installed
 mariadb-client-10.3:i386 : Depends: libconfig-inifiles-perl:i386 but it is not installable
 mediawiki : Depends: apache2 but it is not installed or
                      httpd
             Recommends: php-apcu but it is not installed
             Recommends: php-wikidiff2 but it is not installed
             Recommends: python3 but it is not installed
 mediawiki-extensions-math : Depends: mediawiki-math-texvc (>= 2:1.0) but it is not installable
                             Recommends: mediawiki-extensions-base but it is not installable
 mediawiki-math:i386 : Depends: mediawiki-extensions-math:i386 but it is not installable
 mercurial:i386 : Depends: mercurial-common:i386 (= 4.8.2-1+deb10u1) but it is not installable
 mysql-client:i386 : Depends: default-mysql-client:i386 but it is not installable
 nagios-plugins-basic : Depends: monitoring-plugins-basic but it is not installed
 openssl-blacklist : Depends: python but it is not installed
 perl-modules-5.24 : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.24.1-1) but it is not installed
                     Recommends: perl (>= 5.24.1-1) but it is not installed
 perl-modules-5.28 : Depends: perl-base (>= 5.28.1-1) but it is not installed
                     Recommends: perl (>= 5.28.1-1) but it is not installed
 php-apcu:i386 : PreDepends: php-common:i386 (>= 2:69~) but it is not installable
 php-apcu-bc:i386 : PreDepends: php-common:i386 (>= 2:69~) but it is not installable
 php-bz2 : Depends: php7.3-bz2 but it is not installed
 php-cli : Depends: php7.3-cli but it is not installed
 php-curl : Depends: php7.3-curl but it is not installed
 php-gd : Depends: php7.3-gd but it is not installed
 php-intl : Depends: php7.3-intl but it is not installed
 php-mbstring : Depends: php7.3-mbstring but it is not installed
 php-mysql : Depends: php7.3-mysql but it is not installed
 php-soap : Depends: php7.3-soap but it is not installed
 php-wikidiff2:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:7.0+33~) but it is not installable
 php-xml : Depends: php7.3-xml but it is not installed
 php-zip : Depends: php7.3-zip but it is not installed
 php5 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u9~) but it is not installable or
                 libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u9~) but it is not installable or
                 php5-cgi (>= 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u9~) but it is not installable or
                 php5-fpm (>= 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u9~) but it is not installable
        Depends: php5-common (>= 5.6.40+dfsg-0+deb8u9~) but it is not installable
 php7.0-bz2:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.0-common:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.0-gd:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.0-intl:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.0-json:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.0-mbstring:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.0-mysql:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.0-opcache:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.0-readline:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.0-soap:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.0-xml:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.0-zip:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.3 but it is not installed or
                   php7.3-fpm but it is not installed or
                   php7.3-cgi but it is not installed
          Depends: php7.3-common but it is not installed
 php7.3-bz2:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-common:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-curl:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-gd:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-intl:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-json:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-mbstring:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-mysql:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-opcache:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-readline:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-soap:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-xml:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 php7.3-zip:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:35) but it is not installable
 phpmyadmin : Depends: php-json
              Depends: perl but it is not installed
              Recommends: apache2 but it is not installed or
                          lighttpd but it is not installed or
                          httpd
 pure-ftpd-common : Depends: libpam-modules but it is not installed
                    Depends: perl but it is not installed
                    Recommends: pure-ftpd
 pure-ftpd-ldap:i386 : Depends: pure-ftpd-common:i386 (= 1.0.47-3) but it is not installable
 python-certifi : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not installed
                  Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
 python-cryptography:i386 : Depends: python-asn1crypto:i386 but it is not installable
                            Depends: python-enum34:i386 but it is not installable
                            Depends: python-ipaddress:i386 but it is not installable
 python-openssl : Depends: python-cryptography (>= 2.3) but it is not installed
 python3-acme : Depends: python3-cryptography (>= 1.2.3) but it is not installed
 python3-certbot : Depends: python3-cryptography (>= 1.2.3) but it is not installed
                   Depends: python3-zope.interface but it is not installed
 python3-cryptography:i386 : Depends: python3-asn1crypto:i386 (>= 0.21.0~) but it is not installable
 python3-distutils : Depends: python3 (>= 3.7.1-1~) but it is not installed
                     Depends: python3 (< 3.8) but it is not installed
 python3-josepy : Depends: python3-cryptography (>= 0.8) but it is not installed
 python3-lib2to3 : Depends: python3 (>= 3.7.1-1~) but it is not installed
                   Depends: python3 (< 3.8) but it is not installed
 python3-openssl : Depends: python3-cryptography (>= 2.3) but it is not installed
 python3-zope.component : Depends: python3-zope.hookable but it is not installed
                          Depends: python3-zope.interface (>= 4.1.0) but it is not installed
 sasl2-bin:i386 : Depends: db-util:i386 but it is not installable
 sendmail-base : Depends: make
 stunnel : Depends: stunnel4 (>= 3:4.20-3) but it is not installed
 sysv-rc : Depends: insserv (> 1.12.0-10) but it is not installed
 update-inetd : Depends: perl but it is not installed
 z-push-config-apache : Depends: apache2 but it is not installed
                        Depends: libapache2-mod-php or
                                 libapache2-mod-php5 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I run `apt --fix-broken install`, the system breaks completely, removing apt/dpkg.

The sources.list looks unspectacular (it points to a local approx instance):

```
deb http://apt-proxy:9999/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb http://apt-proxy:9999/security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://packages.prosody.im/debian stable main
deb http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian buster-backports main
# z-push
deb http://repo.z-hub.io/z-push:/final/Debian_8.0/ /
```

For reference, I have put the output of `apt-config dump` at pastebin because it is pretty large: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HxTV7jkvws/

The system is Debian buster (upgraded from various versions) and it is a VM/container (lxc right now). I want to avoid reinstall by all means.

How do I proceed?

(I have a ZFS snapshot so I can also do a clean restart)

Comment: Can you post your sources list? Sometimes the sources limit the architecture.

Comment: @juniorRubyist: Thanks, added it (although I do not see anything particularly weird...)

Comment: Are you trying to convert a 32-bit system to 64-bit?  You need to reinstall it if so.

Comment: Could you add the output of `apt-config dump`

Comment: Yes, 32 to 64 bit. Reinstall is what is want to avoid by all means. Why a “cross grade “ is not officially supported, it should work (see the link in my posting). Furthermore, I successfully did it already once 10 years ago or so (probably in etch).

Comment: @juniorRubyist : Thanks, also added that.

Comment: Actually, I think I was able to fix it: `dpkg --get-selections >file`. Then replacing `:i386` by `amd64` in the file and `dpkg --set-selections < file`. Then repeat `apt install -f`. It didn't go smoothly but at least it didn't destroy the system...

Comment: @divB I was going to say that you would need to transition all of the packages to the amd64 packages. I was also thinking that you need to remove the i386 from your architectures list in your apt configuration, but there are so many config files that it is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 2):

To convert any application or operating system from 32-bit to 64-bit, you must uninstall the application and install the 64-bit application counterpart,or to convert a whole operating system, to 64-bit, you must back everything up and reinstall the operating system.  This is always true, as the conversion to 64-bit is more than an update can withstand.

Comment: Debian has a "documented" cross-grade process for switching between any two architectures supported by the hardware.  See https://wiki.debian.org/CrossGrading.  It is still dangerous (see this question) but its doable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you needed to include "perl-base:amd64" and "apt-utils:amd64" in the set of packages to installed together with `dpkg` and `apt`.  On more recent Debian installs you might need to also include "libsystemd0:amd64" in the initial crossgrade of the installers.